# Countif Syntax Excel-VBA is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

```
Range("G12").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!D:D,'test'!E6,'TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!C:C,'test'!C12,'TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!BR:BR,"">0"")"
```

I have tried different ways to make this work using different syntax around the >0 but nothing seems to be working.... This just would count up the amount of employees that the manager has under them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the criteria needs to end up being `"<"&0`

So the formula should be;

```
Range("G12").Formula = "=COUNTIFS('TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!D:D,'test'!E6,'TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!C:C,'test'!C12,'TECH DETAIL (ALL)'!BR:BR,"">""&0)"
```

Comment: I appreciate it.... for what ever reason 2 hours later after I posted this up, Excel-VBA took my syntax and started working with the "">0""